# How to enable CORS for simple AJAX web application

Tags: ajax, crossdomain.xml

I have searce a lot of solutions about AJAX call CORS, but I still can not get XML data from that other server.

This is console note:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load url.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access

I have follow instructions from: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ section: CORS from jQuery, this is code that I try:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'http://www.someurl.xml',
    contentType:'text/plain',
    xhrFields:{
        withCredentials: false
    },
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'http://localhost:8080',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Method':'GET',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type,x-requested-with,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
    },
    success: function(data){
        var test = data;
    }
});
```

I know that this question has been asked for many times, but no answer help to fix my problem.

For testing in localhost I am using IIS 8.5

Answer (score 2):

The `headers` section in your `$.ajax` code adds headers to the request *to* the server, but CORS headers need to be present on responses *from* the server.

Working with IIS, you can add those headers with a few lines in the `<system.webServer>` section of your `web.config`. Adding this will get you started for GET requests:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

See this post for more information: http://encosia.com/using-cors-to-access-asp-net-services-across-domains/

Comment: I try this, but I get this error: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. But still this is no help of me, because I am just testing it in IIS, because server where would be app, server is not using IIS

Comment: @krnekires If you don't have any other web.config yet, you'll need a little more than just the `system.webServer` bit for it to be a valid web.config. Try using this one: https://github.com/Encosia/Encosia-Samples-ASMX-CORS/blob/56efe91729460a8b6baf9f28fe2392244e3e311a/Web.config

Comment: now I got only No 'access-control-allow-origin' note in console. Is maybe something wrong with url that I am getting data? This is url: http://www.meteo.si/uploads/probase/www/fproduct/text/sl/fcast_SLOVENIA_latest.xml (it is public)

Comment: @krnekires It seems like your server is apache, not IIS. Apache will ignore the web.config file. On apache, you can do the same thing by putting `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

The CORS headers must be *sent* by the server you are making the call to, you cannot provide them with the request itself.

When making a request across domains, your browser will perform a preflight request to get the relevant CORS headers before actually requesting data (I believe this uses the OPTION method).

If the CORS headers from preflight include the current origin or a wildcard matching it, then the browser will continue on with the real request and fetch some data.