# how to Jquery ajax post getting value in clasic asp

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, asp-classic

I am trying to populate auto complete list by typing on textbox using jquery AJAX:

This is my code:

```
$("#formLoc").keyup(function(event){
    var keyword = $("#formLoc").val();
        if(keyword.length){
            if(event.keyCode != 40 && event.keyCode != 38 && event.keyCode != 13){
                $.ajax({
                    'type':'GET',
                    'url': 'AIR_NAME_SEARCH_2.ASP',
                    data: "locKeyword="+keyword,
                    success: function(responseText){
                        alert(responseText);
                        if(responseText != 0){
                            $(".ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(msg);
                        }else{
                            $(".ajax_response").fadeIn("slow"); 
                            $(".ajax_response").html('<div style="text-align:left;">No station found!</div>');
                        }
                    }
            });
        }
});
```

**AIR_NAME_SEARCH_2.ASP**

```
<% @LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001" %>
<!--#include file="include/dataconn2.asp"-->


<%
set AIR=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
AIR.Open "select * from AIR_AIRPORT_INDIA WHERE AIRPORT_CODE = '" + Request.QueryString("locKeyword") + "' OR AIRPORT LIKE '" + Request.QueryString("locKeyword") + "%' ORDER BY AIRPORT",conn,1,3,1

RESPONSE.WRITE "<ul class='list-group'>"
FOR I=1 TO AIR.RECORDCOUNT
RESPONSE.WRITE "<li class='list-group-item'><a href='javascript:void(0);'><span class='bold'></span>" + AIR.FIELDS("AIRPORT") + "-" + AIR.FIELDS("AIRPORT_NAME") + " [" + AIR.FIELDS("AIRPORT_CODE")+ "]" +  "</a></li>"
AIR.MOVENEXT
NEXT
RESPONSE.WRITE "</ul>"
%>
```

All i get is "retuned" and nothing after that. I check in firebug.
Also I change the 'type':'GET' & request.form("locKeyword"), but nothing return. IF I directly hit this url (AIR_NAME_SEARCH_2.ASP?locKeyword=k) on browser i will return file.
What would i be doing incorrect?

Comment: you need to mention the data type in your ajax. Ex : datatype : json

Comment: what is this `msg` in `$(".ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(msg);` It probably should be `responseText`?

Comment: oops!  you are right. Its $(".ajax_response").fadeIn("slow").html(responseText);

Comment: @SandipKr So does it work now?

Comment: @Zealander, No Its not work. Nothing reply form ajax. You want to see the live url?

Comment: Sure, post your url.

Comment: Check in first textbox: http://qubedns.co.in/codes/design/rnp/flight-search.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94644/discussion-between-sandip-kr-and-zealander).

Comment: @SandipKr, you have CORS issue. See the error in the console `http://103.231.43.134/NewRetailer/AIR_NAME_SEARCH_2.ASP?locKeyword=a. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://qubedns.co.in' is therefore not allowed access.`  Your server at `103.231.43.134` needs to allow cross-origin calls. To get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748338/how-to-enable-cors-for-simple-ajax-web-application

Comment: So how to I enable this? thanks

Comment: Depends on your server. You basically need to add HTTP headers to allow Cross-Origin. Search for "CORS + type of your server" i.e. "Enable CORS IIS7" Or ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I have search for above issue over internet, I am confusing on adding header in web.config. Can you send me the exact code to accept GET & POST method @ Zealander